# wget start php function passing login

Tags: cron, wget

In cPanel I try to setup a cronjob like:

```
wget -O- --user=name --password='secret' /home/public_html/admin/import.php?cmd=trans
```

But this is not working. Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an URL in wget instead of an absolute path. Try something like `http://localhost/.../admin/import.php?cmd=trans` instead of `/home/.../public_htmi/admin/import.php?cmd=trans`.

Without knowing your detailed setup I cannot tell you though what to put in for the ellipsis.

Without specifying an URL, wget may assume the file:// protocol. This is fine for static files, but this will not execute the php code, as this happens on the http server side during a proper http request.